# Java Generic Advanced Usage

Tags: java, generics, java-8, generic-programming

The problem is that the following code can't compile if the generic signature consists of several `?` which are the same type.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Test {

    private static <T> T findSelfReference(Map<T, T> map) {
        for (Map.Entry<T, T> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey() == entry.getValue()) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static <T> T findSelfReference2(Map<T, T> map) {
        for (T key : map.keySet()) {
            if (map.get(key) == key) {
                return key;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Question: How to write the method signature that can ensure compile-time type safety? Both the signatures fail to compile.

    // private static <T> String fun(Function<Map<T, T>, T> finder) {
    private static String fun(Function<Map<?, ?>, ?> finder) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        // some processing to map1
        Integer n = finder.apply(map1);  // usage here, compile-time type checking wanted

        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        // other processing to map2 depending on n
        return finder.apply(finder, map2);  // another usage
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Please don't change into helper class...
        System.out.println(fun(Test::findSelfReference));
        System.out.println(fun(Test::findSelfReference2));
    }
}
```

In `fun`, inside each call to `finder.apply()` the type `T` is fixed. But among different calls they use different types. I tried the wildcard capture (ref: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html)) but no luck.

I don't want to cast the result into Object in which the checking has to be made in runtime. All type checking should be done in compile time.

Is it possible without making O(n) helper classes where n is the number of inline function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you want the `finder`'s `apply` method to be generic.

The solution is to define your own functional interface with a generic method.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Finder {
    <T> T apply(Map<T, T> map);
}

private static String fun(Finder finder) {
    // same body
}
```

If this counts as a "helper class" then I don't know what to tell you. You are trying to pound a square peg in to a round hole. `Function#apply` isn't a generic method so you can't do this with `Function`.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to achieve with your method `fun`?

You pass it a `Function` with either wildcards or with a type parameter `T` and then you want to apply it on two different, concrete types (`Integer` and `String`).

This is not going to work:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
// ...
Integer n = finder.apply(map1);
```

Because here you expect `finder` to take the type `Integer`, but you've specified in the declaration of `fun` that either the type is unknown (if you declare it with `?`) or with some unbounded type `T` (if you declare it with a type parameter `T`). But if you're going to apply it to `Integer` you need a `Function<Map<Integer, Integer>>`, not a `Function<Map<?, ?>, ?>` or a `Function<Map<T, T>, T>` for some unbounded type `T`.

You could write it like this - but the method `fun` itself is more or less useless.

```
private static <T> T fun(Map<T, T> map, Function<Map<T, T>, T> finder) {
    return finder.apply(map);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put(1, 2);
    map1.put(3, 4);
    map1.put(5, 7);
    map1.put(2, 2);
    map1.put(8, 8);
    Integer n = fun(map1, Test::findSelfReference);

    String a = String.valueOf(n + 1);
    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("1", "2");
    map2.put("3", "4");
    map2.put("5", "7");
    map2.put("3", a);
    String s = fun(map2, Test::findSelfReference2);

    System.out.println(n);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do something like this:

```
private static <T> T fun(Function<Map<T, T>, T> finder, Map<T, T> map) {
    return finder.apply(map);
}

private static Map<String, String> getStringMap(Integer n) {
    String a = String.valueOf(n + 1);
    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("1", "2");
    map2.put("3", "4");
    map2.put("5", "7");
    map2.put("3", a);
    return map2;
}

private static Map<Integer, Integer> getIntMap() {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put(1, 2);
    map1.put(3, 4);
    map1.put(5, 7);
    map1.put(2, 2);
    map1.put(8, 8);
    return map1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fun(Test::findSelfReference, getIntMap());
    fun(Test::findSelfReference, getStringMap(1));
}
```

I dont see the purpose of `fun` method, when you can always do this:

```
Function<Map<Integer, Integer>, Integer> m = Test::findSelfReference;
m.apply(getIntMap());
```